# How to redirect to a view with argument from urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I want this url :

```
url(r'^$', 'static_pages.views.specific_static_page', name='index'),
```

to redirect to this view :

```
def specific_static_page(request, static_page_slug):
```

I can't use redirect_to from generic views because this view is using i18n url patterns,
which means I don't know what the url is going to be.

Writing a view only to redirect seems kinda pointless. Is it possible to redirect to a view with argument from urls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the url as you mentioned

```
url(r'^$', 'static_pages.views.specific_static_page', name='index'),
```

and updating view to

```
def specific_static_page(request, static_page_slug=None):

if not static_page_slug:
    static_page_slug = some_default_value #for index page

....
```

may work.